# Ensure correct username when using pg_restore

Tags: postgresql, restore, heroku

I have just installed postgres 9.1.6 on a local Ubuntu server. Now I'm trying to restore a database dump from a database on Heroku. The local database is setup like this:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "create user app_user with password 'pass';"
sudo -u postgres psql -c "create database app_production owner app_user;"
```

Now, when I try to restore the the dump I use the following command:

```
pg_restore --verbose --schema=public --no-acl --no-owner --jobs=8 --exit-on-error --username=app_user --dbname=app_production /tmp/app_production.dump
```

Now in psql with `\l` to see ownerships I get the following:

```
                                         List of databases
          Name    |   Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges  
------------------+-----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 app_production   | postgres  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres         | postgres  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0        | postgres  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                  |           |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1        | postgres  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                  |           |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

As you can see, the ownership of app_production database has now turned from app_user to postgres. I would have expected the owner of the app_production database to still be app_user, so what am I doing wrong?

BTW, The `--schema=public` was added, because I was getting a weird error:

> "Could not execute query: ERROR:  must be owner of extension plpgsql"

Another thing is, that the owner of the dump is the user that the database was having on heroku, which would be something like `'jebf473b73bv73v749b7'`

Comment: You may remove the `--dbname` option. This will output a SQL script containing all the restore commands instead of actually restoring. Then you can look near the beginning of that output for any `ALTER DATABASE` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create the plpgsql extension I believe you have to be Superuser.  My recommendation is to make app_user temporarily a superuser and then revert this.  Superusers also are treated as owners of everything.

```
ALTER USER app_user WITH SUPERUSER;
```

run the restore, then when you are done

```
ALTER USER app_user WITH NOSUPERUSER;
```

This should avoid any other permissions issues but still leave you with the permissions you want.